# In batch SET /P command "?" crashes with "was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file, set, prompt

It sounds I can't put "?" in prompt in batch (.bat) scripts:

```
set /p AREYOUSURE= Are you sure (Y/[N]) ?
```

It crashes with the message :

> ? was unexpected at this time.

However, it works well without the ""

Note: I'm running with Windows 7 64bits.

Comment: I suggest you to add "**in SET /P command**" in the topic title! The "prompt in batch scripts" is an entirely different thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't because of the question mark, it's because of the closing parenthesis. You are using this statement in a block, e.g.

```
if foo (
  set /p AREYOUSURE= Are you sure (Y/[N]) ?
)
```

The closing parenthesis closes the block, which then lets the parser stumble over the first character *after* the block.

You can escape the closing parenthesis:

```
set /p AREYOUSURE= Are you sure (Y/[N]^) ?
```

or just use quotes, which I'd always recommend anyway:

```
set /p "AREYOUSURE=Are you sure (Y/[N])?"
```

For questions like these I'd personally use `choice`, however:

```
choice /m "Are you sure"
```

You can't do a default choice when just pressing return that way, though.